# Notation for singular measures

Tags: measure-theory

I have a simple question: Is the notation $\perp$ for singular measures related to orthogonality?   For me, it would make sense if I can provide an inner product to the set of (complex) measures, but I have no idea if there is one (as far as I know there is no one)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Measures form a Banach algebra but not a Hilbert space.

Comment: If you have an inner product for the space of complex measures corresponding to total variation norm then, by restriction (to absolutely continuous measures) you will get an inner product for $L^{1}$, but Parallelogram Identity fails in $L^{1}$.